Enhancing Document Layout Analysis by Adding Positional and Character Information to CNN Inputs
I am working on document layout analysis and have been exploring CNNs and transformer-based networks for this task. Typically, images are passed as 3-channel RGB inputs to these networks. However, my data source is in PDF format, from which I can extract the exact position and character information directly.
I am concerned that converting this PDF data into images for analysis will result in the loss of valuable positional and character information. My idea is to modify the input dimensions of the CNN from the standard 3 RGB channels to a higher-dimensional input that includes this additional positional and character information.
I understand how CNNs work and highly suspect that this approach might not work, but I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions from the community. Has anyone experimented with augmenting input channels in this way, or does anyone have insights into integrating positional and character data directly into CNNs?

I have read some papers where researchers have tried to combine positional and character information with CNNs, but they focused more on a grid-based approach. Grid transformers use such types of architectures.
In the case of word-grid, the approach works by appending the input image with word embeddings, such that the image also contains additional information about the text present in that part of the image. For character-grid, this involves appending a one-hot encoded vector representing each character.
Here are some papers on grid-based methods that might be helpful:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02337
https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06144
https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.06220

These methods cast text with layout information into 2D semantic representations: char-grid and sentence-grid.
